# Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection) in java

Tags: method-parameters

I have checked the above option in **Windows > Preferences > Compiler**.

Earlier it was working fine(I was trying to get the method's formal parameter name  ) but now it is not working.

I am using eclipse Mars and JDK 1.8.0_60

Comment: You might want to post some code to show what's not working, as you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @RichardFearn thanks for your valuable concern. Issue is already fixed , the problem was not in code. Actually I forgot to change the 'project specific settings' , so that was creating the problem.

Comment: Good to know it's fixed. If you feel like it, you could elaborate on your problem, then answer your question yourself. That's encouraged here, and means that others who get the same problem might come across your solution.